# Android. custom bubble/balloon of InfoWindow in Google Maps v.2

Tags: android, image, google-maps, android-custom-view, infowindow

I want to create a custom infoWindow in Google Maps v.2. I have the code but I need 9-patch image. Can anyone tell me where to find free images?

Thanks

Comment: go to [http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool included in the android sdk to create and test nine patch images:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

https://github.com/grassator/rain

also read below guide line:-

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Below are tutorial :-

http://weblookandfeel.com/nine-patch-editor/

http://tekeye.biz/2012/android-9patch-files

http://draw9patch.com/